# Closing all JFrame child starting to main JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

How to close all child `JFrame` starting to main `JFrame`?

My main frame and child frames use `setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);`

Comment: Just a tip: You should consider avoiding [the use of multiple JFrames](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/4857909).

Comment: Since your code creates the JFrames, why not just store them in a List?

Comment: Great answer @LuxxMiner